# issue to fill the positions of a one-dimensional array on c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I´m trying to fill positions on one dimesional array in C#, using three controls: one button, one textbox and one label.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     string[] VECT;
     int i = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VECT = new string[4];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "";
        VECT[i] = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
        i++;
        label5.Text = Convert.ToString(i);


    }
}
```

When the code is compiled,  I start to insert alphanumeric values on the textbox, clicking the button to fill  this array, but when loading is done, the array doesn't preserve data on it's positions.
Please, I need your help to do a wrigth loading on this array.
Thank you.

Comment: You have not come close to explaining exactly what is happening that you don't want to happen, or what you've done to try and fix it.

Comment: `PAR = new string[2];` you  never declare it .. you need to do `var PAR = new string[2];` or declare it further up in your class.. learn to construct a readable `if` conditional statement as well

Comment: Arrays in C# are `0` based that means even with your logic in order to get this to work, you need to change your `if(i==4)` change that to `if(i==3)` also please edit your question and show us what the Textbox Text is and show what the expected outcome is..? are you expecting to print each string as a sing character separated by `-` ? if so.. then you need to do a for loop when the condition is met to so the "string" can be iterated by `1` `char` at at time.